# Get elements width and height

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i get `height` and `width` of element which doesn't a part of **DOM** yet?

**For example:**

```
var t = $('<div style="position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;background-color:steelblue;"  >lalala</div>');

var height = t.height(); // height is 0!
```

Comment: works for me, Chrome on Fedora, the result is 100

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/XStq6/

Comment: Hm...really works. Sorry guys.

Comment: If you're referring to something that doesn't have a height defined in the style anywhere, then, I'm not sure, but I don't think it can have a height until it's rendered somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me as well. You could try

```
var height = t.innerHeight();
```

though as demonstrated in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29hpC/).

If that doesn't work for you (well possible depending on the browser), consider temporarily adding the element to the DOM:

```
var t = $('<div style="position:absolute;height:100px;width:100px;background- color:steelblue;"  >lalala</div>').hide().appendTo('body');
var height = t.height();
t = t.detach().show();
```